# why STL header files have no extension?

Tags: c++, stl, standards

I got this basic doubt.
The STL header doesn't have `.h` extension.

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
```

Is there is any specific reason behind this? Anybody knows history behind this, please share.

**EDIT**:

> @GMan found [Michael Burr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441568/when-can-you-omit-the-file-extension-in-an-include-directive/441683#441683)
>   which addresses this question.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441568/when-can-you-omit-the-file-extension-in-an-include-directive

Comment: Thanks @GMan. My search in SO and Google didn't reveal this. That is because the question linked is bit different. Anyway I feel Michael Burr's answer addresses my question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- The #include directive doesn't discriminate file types (it's just a glorified copy-paste operation) - no automatic adding of .h is happening.
- C++ standard header files are provided without the .h extension
- Sometimes backward compatibility header files are provided by the vendor with the same name with the .h extension added

It all has to do with namespaces. The .h counterparts for C++ standard headers usually #includes the proper C++ standard header (without .h extension) and then issues a bunch of using (something like this):

FILE: iostream.h

```
#include <iostream>

using std::iostream;
using std::ostream;
using std::ios;
...
```

whereas the headerfile without the .h extension does not pollute the namespace with all the defined classes and types.