# Platform-independent way to obtain maximum C++ float value

Tags: c++, floating-point

What’s the best, platform-independent way to obtain the maximum value that can be stored in a `float` in C++?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[`std::numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits)

Answer (score 21):

```
std::numeric_limits<float>::max()
```

Answer (score 9):

[std::numeric_limits](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/limits/numeric%5Flimits/)

```
// numeric_limits example
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

int main () {

  cout << "Minimum value for float: " << numeric_limits<float>::min() << endl;
  cout << "Maximum value for float: " << numeric_limits<float>::max() << endl;
  cout << "Minimum value for double: " << numeric_limits<double>::min() << endl;
  cout << "Maximum value for double: " << numeric_limits<double>::max() << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that the calls to min() for floating-point types return the minimum positive value, not the minimum value.  There's a big difference.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ you can use the [`std::numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) class to get this sort of information.

If [`has_infinity`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/has_infinity) is `true` (which will be true for basically all platforms nowadays), then you can use [`infinitity`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/infinity) to get the value which is greater than or equal to all other values (except NaNs). Similarly, its negation will give a negative infinity, and be less than or equal to all other values (except NaNs again).

If you want finite values, then you can use [`min`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/min)/[`max`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max) (which will be less than or equal to/greater than or equal to all other finite values).

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <float.h>
```

then use FLT_MAX

Comment: standard library headers are best imported without the extension
. See this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441568/when-can-you-omit-the-file-extension-in-an-include-directive for an overview.