# Boost libs are connected but throws erros

Tags: boost

iI'm trying to build the Cryptohaze-tool. I did all that was in win 7 build faq
http://www.cryptohaze.com/wiki/index.php/Windows_7_Build_Setup 
I've build voost 1_49_0, and pointed the way to directody in system paths.
But I get errors like:

```
ch_grt_common.lib(GRTTableSearchV1.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source::mapped_file_source(void)" (??0mapped_file_source@iostreams@boost@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function "public: __cdecl GRTTableSearchV1::GRTTableSearchV1(void)" (??0GRTTableSearchV1@@QEAA@XZ)
10>ch_grt_common.lib(GRTTableSearchV2.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source::mapped_file_source(void)" (??0mapped_file_source@iostreams@boost@@QEAA@XZ)
10>ch_grt_common.lib(GRTTableSearchV3.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source::mapped_file_source(void)" (??0mapped_file_source@iostreams@boost@@QEAA@XZ)
10>ch_grt_common.lib(GRTTableSearchV1.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: void __cdecl boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source::open_impl(struct boost::iostreams::basic_mapped_file_params<class boost::iostreams::detail::path> const &)" (?open_impl@mapped_file_source@iostreams@boost@@AEAAXAEBU?$basic_mapped_file_params@Vpath@detail@iostreams@boost@@@23@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source::open<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >(struct boost::iostreams::basic_mapped_file_params<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > const &)" (??$open@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@mapped_file_source@iostreams@boost@@QEAAXAEBU?$basic_mapped_file_params@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@12@@Z)
10>ch_grt_common.lib(GRTTableSearchV2.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: void __cdecl boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source::open_impl(struct boost::iostreams::basic_mapped_file_params<class boost::iostreams::detail::path> const &)" (?open_impl@mapped_file_source@iostreams@boost@@AEAAXAEBU?$basic_mapped_file_params@Vpath@detail@iostreams@boost@@@23@@Z)
10>ch_grt_common.lib(GRTTableSearchV3.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: void __cdecl boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source::open_impl(struct boost::iostreams::basic_mapped_file_params<class boost::iostreams::detail::path> const &)" (?open_impl@mapped_file_source@iostreams@boost@@AEAAXAEBU?$basic_mapped_file_params@Vpath@detail@iostreams@boost@@@23@@Z)
10>ch_grt_common.lib(GRTTableSearchV1.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: char const * __cdecl boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source::data(void)const " (?data@mapped_file_source@iostreams@boost@@QEBAPEBDXZ) referenced in function "public: virtual void __cdecl GRTTableSearchV1::SetTableFilename(char const *)" (?SetTableFilename@GRTTableSearchV1@@UEAAXPEBD@Z)
10>ch_grt_common.lib(GRTTableSearchV2.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: char const * __cdecl boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source::data(void)const " (?data@mapped_file_source@iostreams@boost@@QEBAPEBDXZ)
10>ch_grt_common.lib(GRTTableSearchV3.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: char const * __cdecl boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source::data(void)const " (?data@mapped_file_source@iostreams@boost@@QEBAPEBDXZ)
10>ch_grt_common.lib(GRTTableSearchV2.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source::close(void)" (?close@mapped_file_source@iostreams@boost@@QEAAXXZ) referenced in function "public: virtual __cdecl GRTTableSearchV2::~GRTTableSearchV2(void)" (??1GRTTableSearchV2@@UEAA@XZ)
10>ch_grt_common.lib(GRTTableSearchV3.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl boost::random::random_device::~random_device(void)" (??1random_device@random@boost@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function "public: __cdecl CHRandom::CHRandom(void)" (??0CHRandom@@QEAA@XZ)
10>ch_grt_common.lib(GRTTableSearchV3.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: unsigned int __cdecl boost::random::random_device::operator()(void)" (??Rrandom_device@random@boost@@QEAAIXZ) referenced in function "public: __cdecl CHRandom::CHRandom(void)" (??0CHRandom@@QEAA@XZ)
10>ch_grt_common.lib(GRTTableSearchV3.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl boost::random::random_device::random_device(void)" (??0random_device@random@boost@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function "public: __cdecl CHRandom::CHRandom(void)" (??0CHRandom@@QEAA@XZ)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you by any chance [using a French compiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22780466/why-cant-my-program-compile-under-windows-7-in-french)? Those cannot be out-foxed

Comment: Seriously though, your libs are _not_ ---connected--- linked, or you're linking conflicting versions.

Comment: @sehe - You nasty little vixen:)

Comment: I made mistake. How can I fix it?

Comment: @sehe If i change path in system variables I get enother error "boost libs not contains" something like that. So, libs are linked? There is my mistake? Thx.

Comment: Your mistake is currently being vague about things that you could just copy/paste. This is not going to work. The edge that experts have when looking at problems comes from _experience_. I've never _experienced_ a compiler _saying "boost libs not contains" something like that_. So, no sorry, you'll have to figure that one out yourself.