# C++ #include <[filename]> but #include <string> is not a filename

Tags: c++, include

**DUPLICATE:**
[When can you omit the file extension in an #include directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441568/when-can-you-omit-the-file-extension-in-an-include-directive/441683#441683)

---

I feel a little cleverer after finding:
[What is the difference between #include <filename> and #include "filename"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename)

But in my code I use `#include <string>`.
`string` is not a valid filename and the angle brackets are not put in `""`.
**Is this a third way of including other files or how do I have to understand this?

In other words, what is `<string>`?**

Comment: "string is not a valid filename". Says who?

Comment: @n.m. Isn't a valid filename either a header file or a cpp file? (.h or .cpp)

Comment: @NoelWidmer Have a look at the files in your system (compiler's) include folder.

Comment: "cpp" doesn't mean what you think it means, please, if you want to say "C++" then type "C++", not "cpp", it will save everyone nedless frustration. Back to your question, a header file name doesn't have to end in `.h`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `string` is not a valid filename

It is. The name of the header file is literally `string`. Search your include paths, e. g.:

```
find /usr/include /usr/local/include -name "string"
```

and you will have some results.

Comment: Do you know why someone would/should name their file just string? Seems very weird, but there certainly is a reason...

Comment: @NoelWidmer The reason is that the C++ standard says that it should be called `string`.

Comment: Please note that you should absolutely avoid naming your own files in that way. It is only standardized for the standard headers. The new naming scheme of header files does not necessarily mean that the filenames of standard header files have no extension from the point of view of the operating system. How include statements for standard header files are handled is implementation defined. C++ systems might add an extension or even use build-in declarations without reading a file. In practice however those files mostly have this name for simplicity.

Comment: I am reading a pdf right now and found the following link in it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441568/when-can-you-omit-the-file-extension-in-an-include-directive/441683#441683

Answer (score 0):

What are file extensions?

They are some OS (popularly windows ) own way to identify file type to use its default app to open it.
Whereas Mac and Linux use MIME for identification of file type.

**“MIME” stands for Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions**

So in this case of library its the same. It is made using MIME type and since our windows os dont need to open that file other than a using specific IDE we are saved form a problem of file identification.