Why can KDevelop syntax-highlighting show codes without suffix?
I'm using KDevelop-5.10 that comes with KDE Plasma-5.27.
I found that KDevelop can show codes syntax highlighting, even through without suffix(*.hpp, *.h), as long as the codes are system headers. e.g:

/usr/include/c++/12/iosfwd
/usr/include/c++/12/iostream


But my headers at /usr/local/include/ can NOT be shown syntax-highlighting, if there's no suffix(.hpp,.h) with them.

How to let KDevelop show my headers(even without suffix) highlighting?
Thanks!

The standard library headers have no extension for historical reasons https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441568/when-can-you-omit-the-file-extension-in-an-include-directive, presumably kdevelop has special cases in it's file your detection to deal with standard library headers. I wouldn't recommend following this convention in your own code, it's likely to cause confusion (as you've already seen). the convention seems to have partly been chosen to distinguish standard library headers from other headers, by following the convention in your own code you're reducing that benefit

The "file name extensions" are not really relevant any more in modern Linux systems. It is a reminiscence to eras gone by ... Today the content of a file is relevant to why "type" of file the OS assumes, not the name extension. You can easily test that: take some PDF file and change the file name extension from ".pdf" to ".png". What file type does dolphin show afterwards? About the difference between "system headers" and "your" header files: I assume the file type detection stumbles about the "#pragma once" ...

@AlanBirtles It looks like that the headers of a third-part lib pqxx(postgresql c++ lib) have NOT suffixes at all! But they are also treated with syntax highlight by KDevelp.  I don't think that KDevelop has a special case for pqxx?
